# Is there any better ways to compare cases between different row in SAS?

Tags: sas

During some data cleaning process, there is a need to compare the data between different rows. For example, if the rows have the **same countryID and subjectID** then **keep the largest temperature**:

```
CountryID      SubjectID     Temperature
1001           501           36
1001           501           38
1001           510           37
1013           501           36
1013           501           39
1095           532           36
```

In this case like this, I will use the `lag()` function as follows.

```
proc sort table;
    by CountryID SubjectID descending Temperature;
run;
data table_laged;
    set table;
    CountryID_lag = lag(CountryID);
    SubjectID_lag = lag(SubjectID);
    Temperature_lag = lag(Temperature);
    if CountryID = CountryID_lag and SubjectID = SubjectID_lag then do;
        if Temperature < Temperature_lag then delete;
    end;
    drop CountryID_lag SubjectID_lag Temperature_lag;
run;
```

The code above may work.

But I still want to know if there are any better ways to solve this kind of questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you complicate task. You can use `proc sql` and `max` function:

```
proc sql noprint;
   create table table_laged as
   select CountryID,SubjectID,max(Temperature)
   from table
   group by CountryID,SubjectID;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want it that way but you code would keep the highest temperatures
So when you have 2 1 3 for one subject if will keep 3. But when you have 1 4 3 4 4 it will keep 4 4 4. Better is to keep simple the first row for each subject which is the highest because of descending order.

```
proc sort data = table;
    by CountryID SubjectID descending Temperature;
run;
data table_laged;
    set table;
    by CountryID SubjectID;
    if first.SubjectID;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit i blindly taken the code from the question without seeing that mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can use double DOW technique to:

1. Compute a measure over a group,
2. Apply the measure to items in the group.

The benefit of DOW looping is a single pass over the data set when incoming data is already grouped.

In this question, 1. is to identify the row in the group with the first highest temperature, and 2. is to select the row for output.

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.SubjectId);
    set have;
    by CountryId SubjectId;
    if temperature > _max_temp then do;
      _max_temp = temperature;
      _max_at_n = _n_;
    end;
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if _n_ = _max_at_n then OUTPUT;
  end; 
  drop _:;       
run;
```

The traditional procedural technique is `Proc MEANS`

```
data have;input
CountryID      SubjectID     Temperature; datalines;
1001           501           36
1001           501           38
1001           510           37
1013           501           36
1013           501           39
1095           532           36
run;

proc means noprint data=have;
  by countryid subjectid;
  output out=want(drop=_:) max(temperature)=temperature;
run;
```

If the data is disordered in `CountryID` and `SubjectID` going into the data step, a hash object can be used or SQL per @Aurieli.